# I am trying to change my MTU but it is not working out as expected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, desktop-computer, mtu

I am trying to change my MTU to "1460" with the tag:

```
netsh int ipv4 set subinterface “WiFi” mtu=1500 store=persistent
```

But it says the error:

> "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Problems with your command: (1) It uses 1500 rather than 1460, (2) The text `“WiFi”` should be `"WiFi"`.